# Sort a list from another list

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

I have a list of string like :

```
    private List<string> __order= new List<string>()
    {
        "M",
        "W",
        "6",
        "PPT",
        "TEA",
        "MH",
        "CLI",
        "BL",
        "GI"
    };
```

I have a list of object which I want to be sort by one of their properties.
I tried something like

```
            var t = from o in _ordre
                join object in listObjects
                on o equals object.Field
                select object;
```

But it doesen't work

Comment: Use `orderby obj.FieldToSortBy select obj`

Comment: `object` is not a `contextual keyword`, it's a standard keyword, so try changing `object` to something else like `obj`.

Comment: What is your definition of doesn't work? Do you get a error, or what is the expected result.

Comment: It seems you are trying to join 2 lists, not sort...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
// assuming some type for your other list
class MyObject { public string Id { get; set; } }

List<string> _order = new List<string>();
List<MyObject> _objects = new List<MyObject>();
var orderedList = from o in _order
                  join obj in _objects
                  on o equals obj.Id
                  orderby o
                  select obj;
```

Or, If you wish to order by the same order of your items in _order, i.e. by index, you could modify your orderby clause:

```
orderby _order.IndexOf(o)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want:

```
var t = listObjects.OrderBy(o=>__order.IndexOf(o.Field));
```

However I would use a `Dictionary` for the `__order` like this:

```
var __orderDict = __order.Select((e,i)=>new {e,i}).ToDictionary(key=>key.e, value=>value.i);
var t = listObjects.OrderBy(o=>__orderDict[o.Field]);
```